# Translation and Rotation of a solid in R3

Tags: linear-algebra

My question is regarding the alignment of a solid placed randomly in R3, which we want to align with the X-axis.  This is an arbitrary shape, which is defined by a set of points which make up the shape, not an equation which describes the shape.

I want to move this shape so that it sits on the +x axis, where the +X axis cuts through the shape at two pre-defined points at the ends of the shape.  I have uploaded an image, which give a cylinder as the arbitrary shape, defining the center point of both ends as the two points through which I want the x-axis to run.

My linear algebra is a little rusty, can I please confirm that I will need to apply a translation matrix to every point in the shape, which might translate "Point A" to the origin, with all other points being translated by the same amount, and then apply a rotation matrix about "Point A" which would land "Point B" on the +X-axis?

Would this rotation matrix be found by determining the angle(s) between the line which passes through both points A and B, and the x-axis?

Thank you, Cheers

[Image to go with the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s130Z.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> can I please confirm that I will need to apply a translation matrix to
>   every point in the shape, which might translate "Point A" to the
>   origin, with all other points being translated by the same amount, and
>   then apply a rotation matrix about "Point A" which would land "Point
>   B" on the +X-axis?

Yes, you can achieve your transformation by some transformation matrix $M$ with
$$
M = R \, T 
$$
where first the translation $T$ is applied to some vector (to have one of the end points translated to the origin) and then the rotation $R$ (to have the other end point lying on thex $x$-axis, or having $y=z=0$), e.g.
$$
T =
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & t_x \\
0 & 1 & 0 & t_y \\
0 & 0 & 1 & t_z \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
\end{pmatrix}
\quad
R =
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos \theta & -\sin \theta & 0 & 0 \\
\sin \theta &  \cos \theta  & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
if it is a rotation within the $x$-$y$-plane.

This transformation acts on vectors in homogeneous coordinates
$$
u =
\begin{pmatrix}
x \\
y \\
z \\
1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: Thank you.  One clarifying question--Your answer applies to a rotation in the x-y plane.  What would it look for in x-y-z?  The shape I need to apply transformation matrix M on is placed randomly in 3D space, so my transformation matrix will be applied in three dimensions.

Comment: Then it gets more complicated, II would suggest to read [Rigid body in three dimensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rigid_body_dynamics#Rigid_body_in_three_dimensions).